# Windows Image Acquisition consistently using 10% CPU and cannot be restarted; upon stopping, image manipulation programs (MSPaint) fail to load

Tags: windows-10, windows-services, image-editing

I've found the main power usage on my computer as of late has been the Windows Image Acquisition service running at 10% CPU constantly. Going into the services menu and pausing the service does not reduce the CPU it uses. Both stopping and restarting the service work, but they don't fully stop OR restart it (image 1) - instead, after several minutes, an error appears (image 2).

[Not fully stopped service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xpAm.png)
(I will edit this text to be the second image once the error shows up - it has taken 20+ minutes to stop at this point)

I've tried looking this up, and other than people suggesting to turn off my printer (a full disconnect of any connection to my printer showed this wasn't an issue), found [this post on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/o304o7/svchost_wia_stuck_at_10_cpu_usage_doing_nothing/) which was deleted, and thus unhelpful. The title, however, matches perfectly the issue I face.

After ""stopping"" this service, image manipulation apps such as Photoshop 2020 and MSPaint take 5-10 minutes to open.

Why is this happening, and how I can fix it?

Comment: Quite possibly a Shell context issue.  Try seeing if Nirsoft.net Shell View helps you. May be like looking for a needle in a haystack.'

Comment: I would point out that you shouldn't have to stop this service.  Photoshop 2020 clearly are using it for some feature.  The way to stop this service would be to switch it to manual, but you would have to do that while in Safe Mode, in order to prevent it from launching in the first place.  There is a good chance that service connected to Adobe would be dependent on this particular service.

Comment: @Ramhound It's constantly using 10% of my CPU and Task Manager reports it as "Very high" power usage. I don't want that kind of drain on my PC, especially when I'm *not using photoshop*.